# Change imageview in widget dynamically in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me that how can i change images in image view dynamically. i have names of images in database table. After every three seconds a random image should appear in the imageview of widget.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You need to start an alarm which triggers a service after some particular time, and there you update the remote views of your widget...

Put this code in your onUpdate method of your widget class:

```
AlarmManager alarm;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            intent, 0);
    if (alarm == null) {
        alarm = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long interval = 500;
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), interval, pending);
    }
```

and put this code as an inner class in your widget class:

```
    public static class UpdateService extends Service {

    BatteryInfo mBI = null;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        if (mBI == null) {
            mBI = new BatteryInfo();
            IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
            registerReceiver(mBI, mIntentFilter);
        }

        RemoteViews updateViews = buildUpdate(this);
        if (updateViews != null) {
            try {
                ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this,
                        BatteryWidget.class);
                if (thisWidget != null) {
                    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager
                            .getInstance(this);
                    if (manager != null && updateViews != null) {
                        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, updateViews);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Widget", "Update Service Failed to Start", e);
            }
        }

        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            if (mBI != null)
                unregisterReceiver(mBI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Widget", "Failed to unregister", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build a widget update to show the current Wiktionary
     * "Word of the day." Will block until the online API returns.
     */
    public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) {

        updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget1);
                updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgAnim, id);

            }
        return updateViews;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: basically to update a widget you need to update its remoteviews, and in order to do that frequently you need to set an alarm which repeats after some time and triggers the service where you change the remote views and apply it to the widget through AppWidgetManager... a short desc..